# Hanuman panchakavacha in any scripture

Tags: hanuman

Is there any mention of hanuman panchakavacha.I mean in any scripture.I know that hanuman pancharoop is mentioned in ramayana but i am talking about mantra??

Comment: It looks like the original  hanuman panchakavacha is part of some text called sudarshan samhita. Do you want mention of the kavacham in other scriptures like puranas etc. or the original source of it ?

Comment: I have read about hanumatkavacha and Hanumat-pancharatna.But never heard of Hanuman Panchakavacha. I am also eager to know.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar i need original source to assure Thanku in advance